# How to add commentator in Winning Eleven 9?

Tags: technical-issues, pro-evolution-soccer-5

I've installed Winning Eleven 9 (Pro Evolution Soccer 5) in my computer, but after I installed it, there is no back sound and commentator when I play it. Is there any missing file on my game? If so, what file is it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://boardgamestips.com/helpful-tips/does-winning-eleven-9-have-commentary/) post, Winning Eleven 9 does **not** have any commentary unfortunately.